# Running C# exe at boot as daemon with non-root privileges on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, automation, minecraft, mono-framework

I am in the process of setting up a "multi-server" (LAMP, MINECRAFT, FTP, SOCKS, FIREWALL, DHCP) on a Dell dimension 4400 I have the LAMP working now I am going for the minecraft server. I have a working install of McMyAdmin but it has no way to start on boot and I do NOT want it running as root EVER so my question is how do i make McMyAdmin run at boot as the user "minecraft"?

Here is all the information on my system:

Output of inxi:

```
System:    Host JUMPER Kernel 2.6.32-5-686 i686 (32 bit) Distro Debian GNU/Linux 6.0
CPU:       Single core Intel Pentium 4 (-UP-) cache 256 KB flags (sse sse2) clocked at 1594.948 MHz 
Graphics:  Card nVidia NV11 [GeForce2 MX/MX 400] X.org 1.7.7 Res: 80x24 Gfx Data: N/A for root out of X
Network:   Card-1 Atheros AR5212/AR5213 Multiprotocol MAC/baseband processor driver ath5k
           Card-2 D-Link System RTL8139 Ethernet driver 8139too
Disks:     HDD Total Size: 360.1GB (1.6% used) 1: /dev/sda ST340016A 40.0GB 
           2: /dev/sdb WDC_WD3200AAJB 320.1GB 
Partition: ID:/ size: 18G used: 5.4G (33%) fs: ext3 ID:swap-1 size: 0.89GB used: 0.13GB (14%) fs: swap 
Info:      Processes 142 Uptime 20:33 Memory 96.2/502.4MB Runlevel 2 Client Shell inxi 1.4.23
```

Using Webmin/SSH for remote administration.

The commands I am using to launch McMyAdmin as root for testing

```
# cd /home/minecraft/McMyAdmin
# mono McMyAdmin.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/rc.local (if you don't want to write an init script):

`su minecraft -c 'mono /home/minecraft/McMyAdmin/McMyAdmin.exe'`

Comment: will i be able to send commands to the application or not? for example when you run the application in the forground sending /quit exits McMyAdmin cleanly. Is there a way to do that now or not.

P.s. my current solution is from root: `su - -c 'screen mono McMyAdmin.exe' minecraft' to start then i detach from the screen. to enter commands i use `su - -c 'screen -r' minecraft` and then when /quit is sent the screen termanates.